# Why am I getting Error (115:103 'var' cannot be used as a variable or function name)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to iron this thing out but debugging is killing me. Line 115 is the "validShort" and "validLong" lines. When I try to save/compile I get the message

"Error at 115:103 'var' cannot be used as a variable or function name."

How can I correct this? Thanks for any guidance.

```
// Check if we have confirmation for our setup
if (Long_Condition)
    validLong = dateFilter and Inside_Bar and Bullish and strategy.position_size == 0 and dateFilter and barstate.isconfirmed

if (Short_Condition)
    validShort = dateFilter and Inside_Bar and Bearish and strategy.position_size == 0 and dateFilter and barstate.isconfirmed
```

Comment: can you post this code in a code block formatted so we can read it a bit easier? thanks!

Comment: Well, the issue is soemwhere else. Please share your complete code or a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe my issue was due to splicing two different versions of pine into one. I had some stuff from v4 and from v5 that I think was causing some kind of issue. Resolved by converting both original codes to v5 and putting it back together.